# Can somebody explain my cmd output

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

[image: the cmd output]

I entered `cd d<TAB-KEYPRESS>` to change the directory, and windows completed the d to "Documents and Settings", which **does not exist** on my hard-drive at this location. So why can i even navigate there? Usually the output for `cd "NonExistingDir"` results in

> The system cannot find the path specified.

My laptop has the latest version of Windows 10 installed.

This doesn't cause me any problems but id like to know why it does that; also I'm wondering if my result is reproducible.

Comment: I believe tab in windows uses a standard directory tree so Documents, Pictures etc. when tab is pressed. As I use linux & mac, tab auto completes a directory tree so if your in ~/ and cd ~/ it will list those relavant directories inside the ~/ (home) directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document and Settings does not really exist as an area on the hard drive. Instead it is a symbolic link that MS has for backward compatible purposes.  If you go to C:\Users you should see the same files & folders.

Comment: that also explains the little arrow on the foldericon. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is (was) a hidden folder, which nobody can access and the owner is SYSTEM.

Changed the owner and removed the deny access to anyone from acl, and look!

[image: correct output]

I think i was able to navigate there because only navigating to the folder doesnt read file list or anything.